# Is it possible to run shell command once before compilation in GNU Make 4.3?

Tags: shell, gnu-make

Should be pretty simple: I have a Makefile that compiles and links a static library. I want to achieve the following behavior:

If there are no changes to .c/.h files:

```
make: Nothing to be done for [target]
```

If there are changes:

```
==> Creating target [target]...  
  -> Compiling source files...  
[compiler output goes here]  
  -> Linking static library [target]
==> Finished making: [target]
```

And yes I do know how dependencies work and how to generate .d files during compilation, what I need is a way to run a shell command **once** before any compilation is done (if there is something to compile).

Comment: Your question is not clear.  What would this shell command that you run once be doing?

Comment: @MadScientist printing status messages, nothing more. I'm thinking maybe set some variable to hold the message and then modify it inside a recipe to contain just an empty string after the first .o file is compiled...

Answer (score 0):

```
PREBUILD_MSG = "$(GREEN)==>$(WHITE) Creating target $(NAME)...$(NOCOLOR)\n"
ifneq ($(findstring $(MAKECMDGOALS), so $(NAMESO)),)
    PREBUILD_MSG = "$(GREEN)==>$(WHITE) Creating target $(NAMESO)...$(NOCOLOR)\n"
endif
PRECOMPILE_MSG = "  $(BLUE)->$(NOCOLOR) Compiling source files...\n"

all: $(NAME)
$(NAME): $(OBJS)
    @printf $(PREBUILD_MSG)
    @printf "  $(BLUE)->$(NOCOLOR) Creating static library archive...\n"
    @$(AR) $@ $?
    @printf "$(GREEN)==>$(WHITE) Finished making: $(NAME)\n"
    @-rm -f .status
.PHONY: all

so: CFLAGS += -fpic
so: $(NAMESO)
$(NAMESO): $(OBJS)
    @printf $(PREBUILD_MSG)
    @printf "  $(BLUE)->$(NOCOLOR) Creating dynamically linked shared library...\n"
    @$(CC) -shared -o $@ $^
    @printf "$(GREEN)==>$(WHITE) Finished making: $(NAMESO)\n"
    @-rm -f .status
.PHONY: so

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPDIR)/%.d | $(OBJDIR) $(DEPDIR)
    @printf $(PREBUILD_MSG)
    @printf $(PRECOMPILE_MSG)
    @$(eval PREBUILD_MSG="")
    @$(eval PRECOMPILE_MSG="")
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -MMD -MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.tmp -c -o $@ $<
    @$(POST_COMPILE)
```

Comment: Note: it's still isn't completely functional as if you run make in parallel, sometimes it would spit out a few compiler messages before the status message is printed. But I'm still happy with the result. Now my Makefile looks somewhat intimidating... Cool! :)